# Datadog - monitor that alert you if the value of the metric does not change for three days

Tags: datadog

I am trying to add new monitor to datadog.
I added the metric to my code.
And I can see this metric on datadog (goto Metrics -> explorer -> Graph).
Now I am trying to create monitoring on datadog that will alert me if the value of metric don't change for three days in a row.
Is it possible to create this kind of monitoring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is in fact possible to send an alert if a metric shows the same value for a fix period of time. 
You can do this by using the diff() function to your query to produce delta values from consecutive delta points and then apply the abs() function to take absolute values of these deltas.

To do this we use the Arithmetic functions available, which can be applied using the '+' button to your query in UI.

For alert conditions in the metric monitor itself, configure as follows:
Select threshold alert
Set the “Trigger when the metric is…” dropdown selector to below or equal to
Set the “Alert Threshold” field to 0 (zero)

This configuration will trigger an alert event when no change in value has been registered over the selected timeframe.

Here is a link to datadog article: https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/faq/how-can-i-configure-a-metric-monitor-to-alert-on-no-change-in-value/